# Drag and Drop parts of an image as separate images

Tags: javascript, django, frontend, ocr, google-vision

I am trying to develop a front-end feature where the user can drag and drop parts of an image (texts detected via Google Vision API for OCR) to different `<div>`s to categorize detected texts on the image. For example, in the picture below, I want 'Moreno', 'Kaffeepads', '40 pads' etc. to enable dragging and dropping these texts on the original image as separate images to other divs.

[image]

However, I'm not completely sure how to implement such feature. I am implementing the backend with Django. Any suggestion would be appreciated.